# CSS content div is pushing below menu div

Tags: css, html, layout

I don't even know how to describe this, I'm still learning and very much a newb.

I have a div for container.

Inside that is a div for menu and a div for content, both float left, side by side.

With most normal content, they stay side by side.  However, in a small browser window, if text takes up more than one line, the content div gets pushed below the menu div, when it seems like the text should wrap instead.

Here is an example, this is driving me nuts:
http://www.motate.org/riders/scottdeleeuw/trip/acknowledgements.php

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `min-width` property. This will resolve your issue.

like if you lower it down to say 800px and the wrapping starts, make the main parent div to have a `min-width`.

**EDIT**

To be more specific with your issue, remove the float from your content class and use a margin left to push the content.

```
.content {
    font: 13px Verdana;
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding: 31px 0 31px 31px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great. If you are satisfied with the solution, you can accept the answer with a green tick and make an upvote. Thank you - @user1981967